# Withdraw Weth from etherscan goerli error

Tags: metamask, etherscan

i would like to withdraw 0.1 WETH to ETH. I have 0.19 WETH on my wallet. i'm using etherscan goerli to do that with address: 0xCCB14936C2E000ED8393A571D15A2672537838Ad i've approve all WETH on my wallet with function approve.
I can deposit ETH correctly.
The problem is when i call function withdraw with 100000000000000000 in parameter, i have this error on metamask:
[image]

Why?
If i proceed, the transaction is pending all time..

Answer (score 0):

You need to check carefully address of YOUR WETH token. In testnet there is multiple WETH tokens.

I've able to successfully withdraw my 0.001 WETH (https://goerli.etherscan.io/token/0xb4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d6).

Additionally, you could check it via read tab, run the method `balanceOf` and provide your wallet address. If it will show you !=0 then at least you have correct WETH token.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation of WETH in the contract you've linked, the owner of that contract can withdraw the goerli ETH stored in there whenever they want by minting WETH to themselves and then calling the `withdraw()` function.

Currently the ETH balance of that contract is 0 and I still see some holders so it's definitely what must have happened. All the holders of WETH from that WETH contract can use their WETH as they would with any ERC-20 but they won't be able to withdraw unless someone else deposits.